# How would I apply Dilworth's Theorem to the following set: $S=\{ 0,1,4,6,7,8,9\}$ where any element $a$ is less than or equal to $b$?

Tags: order-theory

This is the set  $S=\{ 0,1,4,6,7,8,9\}$ under the order defined by divisibility.
I know we have to find antichains and chains, and that the maximum number of partitions of $S$ into chains should equal the cardinality of the antichains, but I don't understand union of chains and how that would fit in it all.

Comment: As a side note: $S$ is not [ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_total_order) by divisibility. Rather, it is only [partially ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition).

Answer (score 1):

A chain is a subset of a partially ordered set in which any two elements are comparable, and an antichain is a subset where any two distinct elements are incomparable.

The size of a maximum antichain in this poset is 4 (for example, all elements of the set $\{6,7,8,9\}$ are mutually indivisible). The minimum number of chains in a partition of this poset into chains therefore is 4 by Dilworth's theorem. An example of such a minimal partition is $\{1,4,8,0\}$ (because $1|4|8|0$), $\{6\}$, $\{7\}$, $\{9\}$.